# Values change when printing from dynamicly allocated memory

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, printing

Ok quick intro. I'm doing a homework on dynamically allocated memory. We need to simulate a CPU using structs and dyn. al. memory. I was testing if my stack functions properly and doesn't overflow. The stack is supposed to be 2 KiB, didn't overflow, but while printing the numbers, few addresses contain other numbers that i didn't put in. Ill just copy it here, and get rid of instruction lists, registers and such, that are not a problem and would make this long.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct cpu {
    struct stack* memory;
};

struct stack {
    int32_t* values;
    int32_t* top;
};

void stackInit(struct stack* stack)
{
    stack->values = malloc(2048);
    stack->top = NULL;
}

void cpuInit (struct cpu* cpu)
{
    stackInit(cpu->memory); //initialize stack
}

void stackPush(struct stack* stack, int32_t value)
{
    if (stack->top == NULL){
        stack->top = stack->values;
        *(stack->top) = value;
    }
    else if (stack->top + sizeof(int32_t) < stack->values + 2048){
        stack->top += sizeof(int32_t);
        *(stack->top) = value;
    }
}

void cpuDebug(const struct cpu* cpu)
{    
    int32_t* auxpt = cpu->memory->top;

    if (cpu->memory->top != NULL)
        for (int32_t i = 0; auxpt >= cpu->memory->values; i++){ 

            printf("Value on the addr %d\n", *auxpt);
            printf("Address of auxpt: %p\n", ( void * )auxpt );
            auxpt -= sizeof(int32_t);
        }

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    struct cpu Cpu;

    cpuInit(&Cpu);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < 550; i++){
        stackPush(Cpu.memory,i);
    }

    cpuDebug(&Cpu);

    return 0;
}
```

And the output looks like this :

```
Value on the addr 133
Address of auxpt: 0x562640529880
Value on the addr 10
Address of auxpt: 0x562640529870
Value on the addr 544108298
Address of auxpt: 0x562640529860
Value on the addr 2016419898
Address of auxpt: 0x562640529850
Value on the addr 1919181889
Address of auxpt: 0x562640529840
Value on the addr 128
Address of auxpt: 0x562640529830
Value on the addr 127
```

Any ideas why is this happening?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `stack->values + 2048` is returning the address `2048*4` bytes higher than `stack->values`. Which is far beyond the allocated space. Pointers arithmetic is tricky, this is why you better use array notation and proper types.

Comment: You're dealing with a pointer to `int32_t` in your stack struct... so when you add/subtract to/from it, it's in units of `sizeof(int32_t)` bytes, not single bytes.  So, eg. `stack->top += sizeof(int32_t);` increments by `sizeof(int32_t) * sizeof(int32_t)` bytes, not just `sizeof(int32_t)` bytes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill remember that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `struct cpu` has an associated `struct stack`, but that stack is not *part of* the `struct cpu`; the cpu merely holds a pointer to a separate stack.  You never initialize that pointer, nor indeed reserve any memory for the wanted stack.  In particular, your `cpuInit()` function does not do this, and your `stackInit()` function depends on it already having been done.

Overall, supposing that each cpu requires only one stack for its lifetime, you would be better off making the stack an integral part of the cpu, so that you don't need to worry about such allocation issues:

```
struct cpu {
    struct stack memory;  // not a pointer
};
```

Having done that, you'll need to change the syntax with which you access the stack's members via the cpu, and you'll need to watch out for other semantic differences, but you can always get a pointer to the stack where needed (such as to pass to `stackInit()`) via the `&` operator.

Comment: Yup, thanks for pointing out, it wasn't supposed to be a pointer, my bad. Thank you again :) We have just learned pointers and with a lot of '*' in my code i started putting them everywhere :D

Answer (score 4):

Man, you must allocate struct stack before access their members (*values* and *top*). You are accessing a non mallocated memory.

```
void stackInit(struct stack* stack)
{
    stack = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    stack->values = malloc(2048);
    stack->top = NULL;
}
```

Following the tricks pointed in the comments, a better solution could be:

```
void stackInit(struct stack** stack)
{
    (*stack) = (struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    (*stack)->values = (int32_t*)malloc(2048);
    (*stack)->top = NULL;
}

void cpuInit(struct cpu* cpu)
{
    stackInit(&cpu->memory); //initialize stack
}
```

In this way, the caller will see the allocated memory in the context of Cpu.memory.

Comment: You're right, but this won't work because the calling function won't get the new value of `stack`

Comment: Why not, the pointer is 'visible' outside stackInit because is a pointer, not a copy, the caller will treat a mallocated memory now, isn't?

Comment: No, @Pablo.  *What the pointer points to* is visible elsewhere via other copies of the pointer.  The pointer value itself is a value like any other -- `stackInit()` receives a copy of the caller's value, and changes to the function's copy are not automagically communicated back to the caller.

Comment: No, it should be `struct stack** stack` and then `*stack = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));`. Or I would better allocate the stack statically inside the `cpu` rather than pointer..

Comment: Or have the call to `malloc` in `cpuInit`

Comment: Thanks for helping, I'll remember the advice, but I realized that the `memory` in  `struct cpu` was not even supposed to be a pointer... But thanks a lot guys.